# CommitLint in yarn v2

Tags: javascript, git, frontend, yarn-v2

there.
I'm trying to set CommitLint and husky in my project with yarn 2 but when I commit, I ran to this problem. Is there any way to fix this? I've tried using 3 commands below:

- `npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"`
- `yarn --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"`
- `yarn run --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"`

I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.6 with Node 14 LTS. My repo is on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/cokaps/blog) (have to bypass the commitlint check)

[Using npx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02yCy.jpg)
[Using yarn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9h6Y.jpg)
[Using yarn run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4QCq.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this with CommitLint Devs. He said that currently it isn't supported. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/issues/2637). And there is a note on the website, too